# How to use Manipulate with ListLinePlot

Tags: graphics, manipulate, recursion, difference-equations

I'd like to run Manipulate with 0<r<=4 that preserves the ListLinePlot of the recurrence table given with the colors shown. I'm looking to use the autorun feature in Manipulate to show how the plot varies with 0<r<=4.

```
(*Logistics Map Model*)
Clear[r, y0, k, NN]
r = 4; y0 = 0.1; NN = 100;
sol = RecurrenceTable[{y[k + 1] == r*y[k]*(1 - y[k]), y[0] == y0}, 
   y, {k, 0, NN}];
ListLinePlot[sol, PlotRange -> {{0, NN}, {0, 1}}, PlotStyle -> Green, 
 Mesh -> Full, MeshStyle -> Red]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To make Manipulate, follows these steps.

1. Decided which variables should be controlled.
2. Make slides/menus/etc.. for each control variable.
3. Write the Manipulate expression which access these variables.
4. Add `TrackedSymbols :> {...}` and list the names of these control variables to help Manipulate know which to track when changed.

The structure is like this

```
   Manipulate[
     expression goes here....last line must end by a comma.
     expression can be a whole module, or just sequence of
     commands. The last line is what you want updated on
     the screen when you change any control variable. This
     is typically a Plot or a Graphics. 
     ,
     control variables go here each separated by a comma
     
     additional Manipulate configurations goes here, such
     TrackedSymbols, Initialization section, etc... see help
  ]
```

Here is your code in Manipulate

```
   Manipulate[
     Module[{y0, NN, sol, y, k},
      y0 = 0.1; NN = 100;
      sol = RecurrenceTable[{y[k + 1] == r*y[k]*(1 - y[k]), y[0] == y0}, 
    y, {k, 0, NN}]; 
     ListLinePlot[sol, PlotRange -> {{0, NN}, {0, 1}}, 
     PlotStyle -> Green, Mesh -> Full, MeshStyle -> Red]
    ]
     ,
     {{r, 3, "r"}, 0, 4, .01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
     TrackedSymbols :> {r}
     ]
```

[image]

Comment: Nasser: Thank you very much ... the structure you show to code Manipulate is  very helpful ... thanks again .. prg